# Wrong path to a Pomm map file

Tags: postgresql, symfony

I'm building a website with Symfony2 and PostgreSQL (for the first time). I've recently discovered the database layer called [Pomm](http://pomm.coolkeums.org/), I decided to use it instead of Doctrine2.

However I get a Fatal Error Exception when I try to display some data. The problem might come from a wrong path to the generated Pomm map file. Unfortunately I haven't found any help in the Manual and the tutorials I read to fix my mistake.

Here is what I did:

**1-** [PommBundle](https://github.com/chanmix51/PommBundle) Installation into Symfony2.3.1 with Composer = ok

**2-** Setup (PommBundle registration in the application kernel + database settings) = ok

**3-** Map file generation for the db table 'product' (as follows) = ok

```
app/console pomm:mapfile:create product
```

Pomm generated the folder 'Database' and now the website structure is:

```
-- Source Files
 |-- Database
   |-- PublicSchema
     |-- Base
            ProductMap.php
         Product.php
         ProductMap.php
 |-- app
 |-- bin
 |-- src
 |-- vendor
 |-- web
```

**4- app/autoload.php**

The PommBundle Documentation about autoload.php is a bit confusing (for a non-native English speaker). Indeed, here's what is written:

> If you are using Symfony 2.0.x, you may still be using sf2 autoloader.
>   Update your app/autoload.php file.

However I'm using Symfony 2.3.1 that's why I thought I don't have to update the app/autoload.php file.

Moreover it's not very clear what you have to add into the file:

```
# app/autoload.php (original file)

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

The PommBundle documentation says:

> Update your app/autoload.php file [by adding the following code]:

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Symfony'          => array(__DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/src', __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles'),
    ...

    'Pomm'             => __DIR__.'/../vendor/pomm/pomm',
    'Pomm\\PommBundle' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/pomm/pomm-bundle',
```

I didn't understand how I could add this code to my file (shown above). So I guessed this was only for Symfony 2.0.*.

**5- Problem in the Controller**

In the COntroller I typed the path to the Pomm map file as follows:

```
namespace Admin\ProductBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
      $myproducts = $this->get('pomm')
         ->getDatabase('database')
         ->createConnection()
         ->getMapFor('Database\PublicSchema\Product')
         ->findAll();

      return $this->render('AdminProductBundle:Default:index.html.twig', 
          array("myproducts" => $myproducts));
   }
}
```

I've certainly done something wrong because I get this error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Database\PublicSchema\ProductMap' not found in
/var/www/mywebsite/vendor/pomm/pomm/Pomm/Connection/Connection.php line 153
```

I'd be very grateful for any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in namespacing.

Symfony trying to call class `MyDatabase\PublicSchema\ProductMap` that should be located in `MyDatabase/PublicSchema/ProductMap.php` file whereas your file located in `Database/PublicSchema/ProductMap.php`

So you should rename the `Database` folder to `MyDatabase` ot Database name to `Database`.

Comment: What you wrote is true but there was a typo in the error message. Actually my database name is not Database or MyDatabase, I just renamed it to make my question more clear (apparently I failed, haha).
Sorry for having confused you, I've just edited the message error. So there is no problem about the database name.

Comment: @Jules have you updated autoload.php as it done in the docs? https://github.com/chanmix51/PommBundle#download-the-files

Comment: Hast: Thanks again for your help. No I didn't update autoload.php, I'm going to edit my question and explain why.

Comment: @Jules ok, i'm waiting for it.

Comment: @Jules sorry, have no idea then. You can try to post your question at the bundle's issue tracker: https://github.com/chanmix51/PommBundle/issues

Comment: @Hast is right, The autoloader does not know where to find the classes for the `MyDatabase/PublicSchema` namespace. This is what you need to add to the autoloader using the `registerNamespace` method.